# How to show that Hodge filtration of CM type is algebraic?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, hodge-theory

I'm asking for a proof or references of the following claim:

> Let $V$ be a rational Hodge structure having CM in the sense that its Mumford-Tate group is abelian. Then there is a filtration $F^{\bullet}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ on $V_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}$ such that the Hodge filtration $F^{\bullet}$ of $V_{\mathbb{C}}$ is given by $$F^{\bullet}=F^{\bullet}_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}\otimes_{\overline{\mathbb{Q}}}\mathbb{C}.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CM Hodge structure is a *polarizable* rational Hodge structure whose Mumford-Tate group is commutative, hence a torus $T$. The Hodge filtration is split by a cocharacter of $T$ over $\mathbb{C}$, which is automatically defined over the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{C}$.

Added: it's the cocharacter $\mu$ such that $\mu(z)$ acts on $V^{p,q}$ as $z^{-p}$. A cocharacter over $\mathbb{C}$ of a torus defined over $\mathbb{Q}^{al}$ is automatically defined over $\mathbb{Q}^{al}$. Since the cocharacter determines the filtration, it also is defined over $\mathbb{Q}^{al}$.

Comment: By "a cocharacter", do you mean the one $\mathbb{G}_m\to M_\phi$ induced by $\phi:\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R})\to GL(V)(\mathbb{R})$? How to use it? On the other hand, shouldn't a representation of a torus automatically decomposes into characters? Why I need a cocharacter?